# Unconventional Hardy-Ramanujan number $a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + c^3$ - can it's existence / non-existence be proven?

Tags: number-theory

> Can it be proven that a number exists such that 
>   $$\text{number} = a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + c^3,$$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are $3$ distinct positive integers?

If it cannot be proven, can it be proven that such a number cannot exist?

Comment: To begin with, $a$ and $b$ must have the same parity, to ensure the sum of their cubes is even. That should help start a proof using $a=2k,b=2j$ or $a=2k+1,b=2j+1$.

Comment: @nij Looking$\pmod{4}$, ll of $a,b,c$ must have the same parity.  Dividing out, we can reduce to the case where they are all odd.

Comment: Moreover, if $a,b$ are coprime and $p>3$ is a prime divisor of $a+b$ such that $p^2\nmid(a+b)$, we have $p\mid c$, so $p^3\mid(a^3+b^3)$ and we easily get a contradiction. Hence the set of numbers for which $a^3+b^3=2c^3$ may hold is rather small.

Comment: As of April 2 at 1:40 a.m. EDT, the Q is trivial, considering the proposer is familiar  with Hardy-Ramanujan numbers,   and therefore probably not what was meant..... BTW Numbers $n=a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$ with $\{a,b\}\ne \{c,d\}$ (all positive integers) are now called taxi-cab numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If such a triple existed with $a<b$, then $a,c,b$ would be an arithmetic progression of cubes.  But it is known that there cannot be three $n$-th powers in arithmetic progression if $n\geq 3$, see for example the paper of Darmon and Morel [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/18.Merel/paper.pdf).

There is probably an elementary proof of this when $n=3$, possibly in the paper of Dénes that they reference.